# Is it possible to write an inheritable extension contract that supports multiple parent implementations?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, erc-721, inheritance

I'm writing an extension to be used with a ERC721 contract. Is it possible to call a function like `balanceOf()` which should be defined in any implementation of ERC721, without having to define the implementation of `balanceOf()`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

interface IMinting is IERC721 {
    function mint() external;
}

contract Minting is ERC721, IMinting {
    function mint() external {
        if (balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0) revert Minting__AlreadyMinted();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, 1);
    }

    error Minting__AlreadyMinted();
}
```

Here's a simplified example, but what I'm wanting is a way to remove the `ERC721` and define that any child contract inheriting `Minting` must also use a 'IERC721' implementation.
This way a developer could choose for example to use OpenZeppelin ERC721 implementation or ERC721A and still inherit this extension.

Is there any was to do this or is this beyond what is possible with inheritance in solidity?

Edit: I've realised that `_safeMint()` is actually defined in `ERC721`, not `IERC721` however the example still works for `balanceOf()` so please look past this oversight.

Comment: Did you try inheriting from IERC721?

Comment: @Ismael Unfortunately this still throws errors as the `Minting` contract is using `balanceOf()` and `_safeMint()` which although are defined by IERC721 they have no function body so are not callable.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I think I found an imperfect but working solution.

Any functions that you expect to be in the parent contract you can define in the extension as a virtual function. This will cause a conflict in the contract that inherits both so the developer must redefine the conflicting function. This can be done with minimally by calling the function from the specific parent contract.

This would be the final code snippet for the above example. Note that `_safeMint(address,uint256)` may not be available in other ERC721 implementations however one could override the virtual function to then call whatever minting function is available in the implementation.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

interface IMinting is IERC721 {
    function mint() external;
}

abstract contract Minting is IMinting {
    function mint() external {
        if (balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0) revert Minting__AlreadyMinted();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, 1);
    }

    function balanceOf(address) public view virtual returns (uint256);

    function _safeMint(address, uint256) internal virtual;

    error Minting__AlreadyMinted();
}

contract Token is ERC721, Minting {
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_)
        ERC721(name_, symbol_)
    {}

    function balanceOf(address owner)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, Minting)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return ERC721.balanceOf(owner);
    }

    function _safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        virtual
        override(ERC721, Minting)
    {
        return ERC721._safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```